# C getline() function: return value vs second argument

Tags: c, pointers, getline, size-t, cstdio

Do the return value (type `ssize_t`) of the [C `getline` function](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) and the second argument `*n` (type `size_t`) contain the same information, after invocation? Empirically, it seems that `*n` equals
`(size_t)pow(2, ceil(log2(<return value> + 1)))`. Is this relation true in general? Can someone explain its (in)validity, conceptually?

Comment: Have you consulted `man getline`?

Comment: Yes, I have. Still having trouble.

Comment: You state in your question that, in your cases, `*n` has generally held a value different from the return value, so no they don't contain the same information.

Comment: As for the relation, it seems that your specific implementation chooses to make power-of-2 size allocations when resizing, according to what's needed. This is not a requirement, but may be a common choice. The buffer just needs to be large enough.

Comment: @ThomasJager By "contain the same information" I mean each can be computed from the other.

Paraphrasing your second comment: the numerical relationship is implementation dependent, but uniquely characterized by the buffer length being the minimal one that is 1) big enough and 2) a power of two. Sounds like an answer to me!

Comment: @fmg "the buffer length being the minimal one" --> no it could be 0 for select reasons and 0 is not a power-of-2.

Comment: @fmg Why is the value of `*n` as potentially a power-of-2 useful to know for your code?  It not relying on _return_value_< `*n` enough?

Comment: @fmg How would you compute the return value from `*n`?

Comment: @ThomasJager You're right. You just get an upper bound. So the answer to my "do they contain the same information" question is "no". More subtle than I initially suspected!

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I don't need this in my code; just trying to understand things. Your point regarding the degenerate case is well taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);`

> Do the return value (type ssize_t) of the C getline function and the second argument *n (type size_t) contain the same information, after invocation?

No.  The return value is the count of characters read, not including the appended *null character*.  `*n` is the *size* of the current allocation of `*lineptr`.  The return value is *signed* and is -1 when an (allocation) error/end-of-file occurs.  `*n` is an *unsigned* type.

It is expected that the return value is always less than `*n`.

> it seems that *n equals (size_t)pow(2, ceil(log2( + 1))). Is this relation true in general?

No, `*n` may or may not be a power of 2.

`getline()` is not part of the C standard library and implementations differ on allocation details.

---

`*n equals (size_t)pow(2, ceil(log2(<return value> + 1)))` is invalid when:

- *return value* == -1
- `getline()` does not re-allocate and the passed in size was not a power-of-2.
- `getline()` reallocates and is not using a power-of-2 scheme.
- Pedantic: Very large *return value* round down in the conversion to `double` in the `log2(_return value_ + 1)` step.
- ...